# jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't do _renderItem in case ajax function source

Tags: jquery-ui

I have created an autocomplete search field with jQuery UI. I can use the code without issues and it generates and shows the results in HTML without issues.

However as I am using more AJAX functionality on the site, and don't want to separate PHP files for doing my queries to MySQL, I want to send 2 pieces of data with my autocomplete. 1 being the search term itself, the other being the name of my function in php so it can identify and find the right query and return data.

With both versions of the code, I can see in chrome's network that the POST is successful and I get my json encoded array of results from PHP.

However in version 2, it doesn't generate the HTML for it with _renderItem.

Thanks in advance!

```
$( "#newInit" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term,
                f : "item_search"
            }
        });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#newInit" ).val( ui.item.name );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#newInit" ).val( ui.item.name );
    $( "#newInit-id" ).val( ui.item.item_id );
    $( "#newInit-weight" ).html( ui.item.weight );
    $( "#newInit-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

    return false;
  }
})
 .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<div>Name: " + item.name + "<br>Weight: " + item.weight + "<img width='30' height=30' src='http://url.com/" + item.icon + "'/></div>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: for version2, check response from ajax. does it really sending list of items with name, weight and icon fields?

Comment: Hi, yes, I do get the proper response back in following form:
[{"item_id":"4","name":"Tool","weight":"1.00","craftable":"0","last_mod":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","icon":""},{"item_id":"7","name":"Wool","weight":"0.10","craftable":"0","last_mod":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","icon":""}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your ajax functon, which will pass the ajax response to autocomplete source.

```
      success: function( data ) {
        if(data) response( data );
        else response({});
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! :)